# How did the author find this integral over a Poisson distribution whose parameter has a exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, integration, poisson-distribution

So my text book on probability theory gives an example of a distribution with random parameters, which after a few paragraphs ends up with this integral:

$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}e^{-2x}dx
&= \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)}2^{k+1}x^{k+1-1}e^{-2x}dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \cdot 1
\end{split}
$$

where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

My question is this: *How in the world did the author calculate this integral?*

---

For those of you who are curious, that integral is the result of calculating $P(X=k|M=x)$ with $M \in \text{Exp}(1)$ and $X|M=m \in \text{Po}(m)$. The example can be found in *An intermediate course in Probability*, 2nd Ed. (Gut, 2009, pp 39).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just doing the substitution $u=2x$ and using $$\Gamma (t)=\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm d x.$$

Comment: I don't see how you can use that equivalence to solve the integral. Can you elaborate?

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty x^ke^{-2x}\,\mathrm d x\underset{u=2x}{=}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\int_0^\infty u^ke^{-u}\,\mathrm d u=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\Gamma (k+1).$$@Mossmyr

Comment: Nooow I see. Then you can cancel the $\frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)}$ found in the equation in my post. But I think you meant to write $\frac{1}{2^k}$ in your comment.

Comment: No, it's $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ (that come from the fact that $dx=\frac{1}{2}du$)